# PreferenceActivity onHeaderClick() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity, slidingmenu, android-holo-everywhere

I have been successfully using `HoloEverywhere`'s `PreferenceActivity` for a while. I am now importing the [`SlidingMenu`](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library and has been going well so far until I extended `SlidingMenu`'s `SlidingPreferenceActivity`:

```
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingPreferenceActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends SlidingPreferenceActivity{
...
```

and

```
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import org.holoeverywhere.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SlidingPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
        SlidingActivityBase {
...
```

In my `SettingsActivity` I load some `Header`'s to show the top level categories.

My problem is now onHeaderClick() is no longer working. I trace it all the way through and cannot find the error. Following the stack trace I see `HoloEverywhere` ends up making an `Intent` it eventually passes to the Android `Activity`, but I don't see anything that is obviously wrong.

***What about the `SlidingMenu` Library could cause Fragments to stop working in a `PreferenceActivity`?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem had nothing to do with `SlidingMenu`. In my manifest I set all my `Activity`s to be `singleInstance`, so that I am not making multiple of the same `Activity` when I am navigating between them using the `SlidingMenu`. This was preventing the `Intent` that was created by `PreferenceActivity` when the `Header` was clicked from recreating the activity with the given fragment.

I removed the `singleInstance` reference for now and everything is working.